# Expected value of a random walk given value at previous time

Tags: random-walk

I have a homework question dealing with random walks. One part of the question required me to find the probabilities $p$ and $q$ such that

$$E[M_1] = M_0$$

which I achieved. Having found these, the next part requires me to use these values to find $E[M_{302}]$ given that $M_{300} = 60$. I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

EDIT:

$$M_n = \sum_{j=1}^N X_j$$

Comment: @Shailesh, I'm sorry. I added the the value of Mn

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to use mathjax/latex to typeset equations.